# Pokemon GO does not work on Samsung Galaxy S3?

Tags: pokemon-go

I have a Samsung Galaxy S3 (I9305) running Android 4.4.4. The play store claims that my device is not compatible with Pokemon GO.

I checked and I know my phone has 2 GB of ram and it should be compatible with Intel processors now, so why can't I download it? I don't want to download an APK because I want to be sure that my device is compatible with everything.

Does anyone know what is the problem?

Comment: Where did you read that they updated it to be compatible with Intel CPUs? I haven't seen that anywhere...

Comment: Intel Processors [still aren't supported](https://support.pokemongo.nianticlabs.com/hc/en-us/articles/221958248-Supported-devices), I don't know where you heard they should be.

Comment: There was whis whole thing and almost 50000 people signed a petition and then the guy that started it said that they sent him an email about it and even apk mirror (I check it sometimes for updates) said Intel something now supported and stuff, and many people say it is now. But do u know how it affects the performance of the app? https://www.change.org/p/niantic-pokemon-go-intel-processor

Answer (score -1):

StrangeAndBizarre said in a [Reddit post](https://m.reddit.com/r/pokemongo/comments/4ri59i/is_there_a_way_to_get_pokemon_go_on_galaxy_s3/):

> I gathered this from a couple different places, download the apk,
>   after you login it gets stuck on blue/green screen. Click the bottom
>   middle of the green screen. A question pops, say no/decline. Keep
>   tapping until professor willow pops up. It should work normally from
>   there. YOU DO NOT NEED TO UPGRADE OS. I'm running it on 4.4.2

The app does work but it's real buggy